# How to safely split strings?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, string

When we want to split a sting for any kind of reasons, we (at least myself) tend to split using the (pipe) `|` character as it is very rare to find out someone or that the application uses it on a string ... but what happens if it uses?

Well, a simple **Crash** will be thrown :)

I found out that a college uses [non-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) chars to do the same technique, for example:

```
String.Format(
         "{1}{0}{2}{0}{3}{0}{4}",
         (char)2,
         myFirstString,
         mySecondString,
         myThirdString,
         myFourthString);
```

and when we want to extract the hole string into it's parts

```
String.Split((char)2);
```

**Is this safe**? **Should I adopt this** way of safely splitting string? **Is there any other** safety technique?

Comment: Difficult to answer without context: how about just flagging pipe as not being allowed? In most contexts that would be reasonable.

Comment: @Timwi, Ok let me rephrase that: in most contexts where it would be reasonable to 'encode' multiple strings in one, pipe should suffice. (Multiple homepages in firefox for instance)

Comment: @Benjol, still no. The only context where it is reasonable is in a context where the strings are not going to contain pipes. **The pipe character is valid in URLs.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It may be “safer” than the pipe because it is rarer, but both ways are suboptimal because they limit you to a subset of possible strings.

Consider using a proper encoding — one that *unambiguously* encodes a list of *arbitrary* strings. The simplest in terms of coding is probably to simply serialize a `string[]`. You could use `BinaryFormatter` or `XmlSerializer` or something else.

If the result *has* to be a string, and it has to be a *short* one, then you could try something like this:

- **Encoding:** (list of strings to single string)

  - Replace every `!` with `!e` and every `|` with `!p` in every string. Now, none of the strings contains a `|` and you can easily reverse this.
  - Concatenate the strings using `|` as a separator.
- **Decoding:** (single string back to list of strings)

  - Split on the `|` character.
  - Replace all `!p` with `|` and `!e` with `!` in every string. This recovers the original strings.

Comment: What if original string has "!p"?

Comment: @Grozz: That would have gotten changed to `!!p` and would still be unambiguous. But I see now that if the replacement is done in two separate passes instead of one, there would be a bug, so to make it easier to implement I changed `!!` to `!e`. Happy?

Comment: +1 for `string[]` and `BinaryFormatter`, which avoid the problem entirely by using a built-in structure for handling this issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is essentially a contract between the applications that *produce* strings in this format, and those that *consume* them - use whatever is appropriate for your situation.

You might want to consider if flattening multiple strings into a single giant string is necessary in the first place. If their reason for existence is is solely for representing 'separated' textual data *within* your application, you might want to produce the data as a sequence of strings (a `string[]` for example) right from the beginning. In this case, no 'parsing' will be necessary.

If, on the other hand, the data must be *persisted* and consumed at a later point, there are several options. For example:

1. **Database**: Store each string as a row in a database table. No splitting is required.
2. **Designated Delimiter**: Store the strings in a flat-file with a 'special' separator that signifies the end of the current string. Obviously, this character must be such that it can't be part of a legal sub-string. E.g. If your strings can't contain a pipe-character as you say, then this is a reasonable choice for a delimiter.
3. **Escape-sequences**: E.g. `*` is the separator, `**` represents an asterisk *within* a string. This will mean that no character is reserved for use as a sentinel (rendering it unrepresentable). On the downside, parsing becomes a non-trivial task.
4. **Purpose-built format**: E.g. XML. When you consider that this requires that certain characters be 'escaped', this is essentially an extension of point 3, but the problem has now been punted to your XML libraries.

Comment: @John: Why? Because it uses lots of buzzwords?

Comment: @Timwi: Thanks for your critiscism. Could you tell me which parts are unclear or use 'handwaving' buzzwords? That is not the intention at any rate, and I would like the meaning to be clearly communicated. Thanks.

Comment: @Ani: Hehe, sorry if I hurt any feelings... there is nothing wrong with your answer, my criticism was actually leveled at John.

Comment: @Timwi: No feelings hurt. Obviously, the OP has a genuine question that deserves some genuine discussion, and I don't want to appear to be throwing buzzwords at a real problem. That's why asked.

Comment: @Timwi, I don't see any buzzwords here, just a clear and well-reasoned answer. Maybe I'm a CIO and don't know it.

Comment: @Timwi, BTW, I upvoted your answer too, even without the buzzwords, right after I upvoted Ani's. I think you both make good points.

Answer (score 2):

It'd be better to never concatenate the strings together in the first place if you can help it. Splitting like this is a code smell.

Sure, using a control character is "more likely" to not have issues, but it's still not perfect. If you really have to do this, use NUL (`\0`). That character at least has a history of being a string sentinel.

Answer (score 2):

I think using non-printable characters is more obscur than safe.
If you want safety, a solution would be to serialize/deserialize your `List<string>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for a normal CSV reader/writer. This helps you because when a value has the separator, it's enclosed in double quotes:

```
a,b,"c,d"
```

produces:

```
new[] { "a", "b", "c,d" }
```

This may help http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the expected content of the string. If the expected strings could have non printable characters then maybe not. The other way is to escape you strings that you are going to split, it looks like more work but could be put into a reusable helper:

```
var string1 = "string|1";
var string2 = "string |2";
var string3 = "string| 3";
var string4 = "string | 4";

var stringToSplit = MergeStrings(string1, string2, string3, string4);

var results = SplitString( stringToSplit );

foreach(string result in results)
{
    Trace.WriteLine( result );
}
```

Which uses the following methods.

```
public string MergeStrings(params string[] strings)
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach(var s in strings)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append( s.Replace( "|", "||" ) );
        stringBuilder.Append( " | " );
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}

public IEnumerable<string> SplitString(string stringToSplit)
{
    var results = stringToSplit.Split( new[] { " | " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );

    return results.Select( result => result.Replace( "||", "|" ) );
}
```

You would probably want to make the separator character customizable.